# Disallowed Key Characters to call server from ios app

Tags: php, codeigniter, ionic-framework, codeigniter-2

I have an issue to call server from ios app showing Disallowed Key Characters. I have _ in my url("http://mydomain/mobileapi/index.php/C_mobileclient/user_login").
I have updated this below code in server Input.php

```
!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}\:\;\.\,\?\!\@\#\$%\^\*\"\~\'+=\\\ &_\/\.\[\]-\}\{]+$/iu", $str)
```

After update this code android app is working, but IOS app is not working and showing this error. (App developed by using Ionic Framework 1)

```
$http({
                url: GeneralService.baseurl+ "/index.php/C_mobileclient/user_login", method: 'POST',
                data: postData,
                headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
            }).then(function(result) { console.log(result);
});
```

This was working well until my php version 5.3 after update php version 5.6 this error occur.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the characters just add it in the following in your codeigniter CONFIG file -

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=\a-z 0-9~%.:_-@$';
```

Comment: This also didn't fix the issue. Still same response comes

Comment: i just gave you an example . you have to add all your special characters to allow

Comment: I have tried with a-z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}\:\;\.\,\?\!\@\#\$%\^\*\"\~\'+=\\\ &_\/\.\[\]-\}\{ these all the character in this config file also